# Need Pattern for password field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, pattern-matching

Length : 8 to 15
Uppercase : min 1
Number : min 1
No Special Characters.

Comment: Please do mind that this is not a place to outsource your development requirements.

Comment: Please show that you tried. There are plenty of similar questions to this already. 10 minutes researching Regular Expressions would give you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Minimum 8 characters and maximum 15 characters at least 1 Uppercase Alphabet, 1 Lowercase Alphabet and 1 Number and No special character allowed:

```
"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,15}$"
```